# Shortest way to say "adjecent to and to the right of"?

Tags: single-word-requests

If we have list of lettters like this: ABCDEFGH

"We can say D is adjacent to E"

But, in English, what is the shortest way to say the "D is adjacent to E on the left hand side?" And what is the accepted norm?

i.e. is there a word for "leftwise-adjacent" or "rightwise-adjacent"?

I wonder if other languages have words for this and what the equivalent in English might be? It would seem like quite useful words to have!

Comment: "D is immediately to the left of E" is how I would say it.

Comment: @JeremyC Please don't answer in comments. If you know the answer, please write it in the answer.

Comment: @DJClayworth If I gave what I put in my comment as an answer somebody would complain that I do not explain why it is the answer, or give references or cross-references to earlier answers. I figured that if the OP wants quick advice my comment will provide it. I have been ticked off before for not explaining why, when I believe that in most cases nobody really knows.

Comment: Not writing it then is the obvious solution. Or taking a few extra minutes to explain.

Comment: I vote to close this question, because it is off-topic.  It is not about English language and usage.

Comment: @Tuffy how so? I don't understand. What's it about then?

Comment: What about 'right adjacent', 'left adjacent' etc. I room is right adjacent to your room!

Answer (score 3):

I would say that D is *just* to the left of E or *just* to the right of C.

Comment: That's good. "Immediately to the left" or "Immediately left of" might also work.

Comment: The question was about the shortest but I would certainly agree with the elaboration.

Comment: I wonder if it makes a difference: 'to the right of' or 'on the right of'. maybe not.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:
D comes before E.

Comment: Yes, I guess this works, since in English you read left to right. But also A comes before E.

Comment: I assumed zooby was looking for a more general term that could apply in other contexts. If I wanted to say that my office is immediately to the left of yours, I can't say "comes before" if the offices can be approached from both directions.

Comment: @nnnnnn good point there.